# Powermail missing absolute links in mails when in lists <ul>

Tags: typo3, powermail

Powermail uses `lib.parseFunc_powermail` to parse the content of mail to sender and receiver. This converts the URLs into absolute URLs and it works.

If URLs are inside of a list `<ul>` this doesn't work anymore. All URLs in the mails are relative.

My try to change TypoScript config:

```
# ParseFunc Configuration for using FAL links in receiver and sender mail
lib.parseFunc_powermail < lib.parseFunc_RTE
lib.parseFunc_powermail.tags.link.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc_powermail.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1

# extended with
lib.parseFunc_powermail.tags.li.stdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc_powermail
```

Does anyone have a tip on how to configure this properly?

Greetings, Heinz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to lines to set absolute urls inside of lists:

```
lib.parseFunc_powermail.externalBlocks.ul.stdWrap.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
lib.parseFunc_powermail.externalBlocks.ol.stdWrap.parseFunc.tags.a.typolink.forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
```